# google scripts event get form

Tags: javascript, forms, google-apps-script

I want to write a Google Script that will collect the answers from 800+ Google forms into one spreadsheet sheet.

By setting the destination spreadsheet for all forms to one spreadsheet, I can have 800+ different sheets in the same spreadsheet. I need to a way to compile these 800+ different sheet responses into ONE sheet.

I am trying to do this by creating an onSubmit(e) trigger for each form. However, when I look at the event e, I can't get information about the event's original form. I can only see the event's FormResponse.

Does anyone know how I can get the source form from a trigger Google form event?

Comment: Are all the forms in one folder?  In known folders?  In order to get 800 forms, you will either need all the Form file IDs, or know which folders they are in, or be able to filter them by some criteria, like something in the file name.  an "On Form Submit" trigger can either be in the project bound to the Form or the project bound to the spreadsheet; either one or both.  If it's in the project bound to the Sheet, there is no `source` object for the event object in a trigger bound to the Sheet.